# how to dynamically create view group?

Tags: java, android, listview, footer, viewgroup

I have a list view.

I want to add footer.

So i create a footer xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100px"
android:background="@drawable/background_news_list"
android:gravity="center" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_more"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_more_news" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want inflate entire layout into main java but i manage to inflate button only

```
footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.testing, null, false);
btnmore = (ImageButton)footer.findViewById(R.id.btn_more);

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
lv.addFooterView(footer);
```

my list is in this xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/layout_menu"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout_title"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

How do i create a viewgroup to fulfill and become like this?

```
footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.testing, parent, false);
```

So that i can use my own linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a little confusing but I think you just need to add an id to your LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/linlayoutid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:background="@drawable/background_news_list"
    android:gravity="center" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_more"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_more_news" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then grab the linear layout:

```
footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.testing, null, false);
LinearLayout ll = footer.findViewById(R.id.linlayoutid);

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
lv.addFooterView(ll);
```

Comment: the footerview did not use the linear layout of footer xml

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this

```
footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.testing, lv, false);
```

This is because

```
lv is the list id and it
```